# Normal Distribution, percent less than mean minus one std. dev

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, means, gre-exam

GRE Question, part b. My answer is 16%, but the book says 15%. Why?

mean = 65 cm
stdev = 5 cm

Probability that penguin chosen at random will be less than 60 cm is 16%, it shows in Normal Distribution graph. Why would the book say it is 15%

[image]

#### Update

During GRE, we can use standard calculator, i.e no scientific calculator. And I don't believe they will provide standard distribution table.

Kindly explain how to DERIVE the 15%, I wish to understand the mathematics.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla I need to know how they got the answer for the actual GRE exam

Answer (score 0):

The percentages shown in your diagram are only approximates. To more significant figures your answer should be 15.866..% so both your answer and the book answer are just rounded differently.

If you look at the question it states: **"Give your answer to the nearest 0.05."**

Comment: Where would I get 15.866,,,% from?

Comment: A standard distribution table, a statistical calculator, the internet, ... $$$$http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=one+standard+deviation+from+the+mean

Comment: @ian-miller During the GRE exam, we will be given simple 4-function calculator, and I don't think they will give standard distribution table. How to derive these numbers?

Comment: You don't. You read it off the graph then you follow the instruction - **"Give your answer to the nearest 0.05."**